# Apache Ignite Ack Back

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, distributed-caching, apacheignite, in-memory-data-grid

I am exploring Apache Ignite with Spring Boot, and I have a requirement to ensure data is restored into in-memory even after server reboots, and I need acknowledgements for data insertion. Is there an in-built acknowledgement feature in Apache Ignite for this, and are there any resources for integrating Apache Ignite with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

By default, writes into Ignite are synchronous, meaning that if it returns, then the data has been correctly stored. You can influence what "correctly stored" means using the [`writeSynchronizationMode`](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuring-backups) option when you create your tables.

The documentation includes references to [Spring Boot](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-boot), [Spring Data](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-data) and [Spring Caching](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-caching), depending on how you want to build your application.